# Как сделать многослойную выборку

Tags: html

Есть `html` код выборки

```
<select class="servise_up_tab1" >
          <option selected="" disabled="">Выберите абонемент</option>
          <option>Сауна</option>
          <option>Бассейн</option>
        </select>
```

Я хочу, чтобы при выборе Сауны открывалось

```
<select class="servise_up_tab1" >
              <option selected="" disabled="">Выберите сроки</option>
              <option>1 месяц</option>
              <option>2 месяца</option>
            </select>
```

а при выборе Бассейна уже другое

```
 <select class="servise_up_tab1" >
                  <option selected="" disabled="">Выберите сроки</option>
                  <option>3 месяца</option>
                  <option>4 месяца</option>
                </select>
```

Также чтобы были комментарии при выборе Определенного срока, что-то типа: `Примечание: При выборе этого срока может взиматься дополнительная плата` и подсчитывалась цена. Пример: Сауна -> 1 месяц -> Комментарий + цена

Comment: Что из перечисленных задач Вы сделали и с чем возникли трудности? Напишите в вопросе часть кода с которым у Вас возникли проблемы

Comment: @RaZik код я написал выше, но он делает все 3 выборки а мне так не нужно

Comment: "Я хочу, чтобы при выборе Сауны открывалось ..., а а при выборе Бассейна уже другое ..." - Как Вы это пробовали реализовать? Как пробовали реализовать подсчет цены и вывод комментариев? У option как минимум должен быть атрибут value

Comment: @RaZik В том и дело, что я не знаю как это реализовать. Я знаю, что такое бывает